# Test Management Tool for managing multiple projects

Tags: automated-testing, test-management, test-planning, jira, katalon

I am looking for recommendations on Test Management Tools.

To start it would be mainly for manual testing, but we would like to integrate with our automated tests in the future. Ideally we would be running these automated tests off of BitBucket (Created using Katalon). It would also be nice to have it linked to JIRA for easy issue creation, as well as maintaining a history of past issues for a Test Case.

We are a consulting firm that has many clients with different projects, and underlying frameworks that should work with many of our clients.
For the frameworks, it would be nice to be able to associate multiple projects for a test.
For the specific projects, it would be nice to associate tests to just that project.

I am also looking for a Test Management Tool that will allow me to create and organize tests easily.

It would be ideal if the Tool utilized pre-conditions or if it was simple to add a specific tag to a group of newly created tests. I want to reduce the amount of time it takes to create a test plan.

I would also like for it to be simple to maintain. In other words, easy to find test cases for a particular area and edit them if need be, or to generate a test plan on the Fly.

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: Isn't structured text files, grep and some scripts to communicate with Jira's API sufficient for what you want to do?

Comment: It's more that I want the test cases to be better organized. We are currently using Google Sheets and I find it to be very inefficient.
I'm not sure if structured text files would work for me, especially when you consider that I eventually want to link it to our automated testing.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend TestRail. It also have API integration.

Comment: A great answer, especially when it comes to recommendations, expands on the why much more than it does the what. Could you elaborate on why you recommend TestRail?

Answer (score 0):

From personal experience I would recommend using opensource [Kiwi TCMS](https://kiwitcms.org).

It has:

- JIRA integration
- Powerful API to work with automated test reporting
- Simple way for organizing manual tests (albeit the GUI part will get better when it will be fully migrated to patternfly)

Comment: Please elaborate on why the down-vote? It is a Test management tool and has the functionalities that OP specified.

Comment: It's not your fault really - this isn't a good question. It has no correct answer, multiple different technologies could fit the bill essentially turning it into a popularity contest.

Comment: @corsiKa That's a good point about it not being a good question. I was just hoping to get some varied responses. As when you try to look into it, you are basically bombarded with marketing as opposed to real opinions about each technology.

Answer (score 0):

As a QA company, we recommend to use Test Rail as it has a good structured approach which helps in organizing the Test Cases as well. Moreover, you can also add custom fields as prt project requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You've mentioned that ease of use is one of your main priorities and therefore, I'd recommend taking a look at [TestLodge](https://www.testlodge.com/).

Answer (score 0):

We currently used as an alternative xray and zepheyer for a customer the Kiwi-TCMS which we have adapted via plugins to a CI/CD solution accordingly.

Advantages Open Source, huge community, easy to integrate into AWS and EC2 systems via Docker, extensible via plugins.

Background information:

Automation inside of Kiwi tcms
https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/automation-frameworks.html

Creating, administering, and managing test plans, test cases, and test runs is incredibly easy in Kiwi. And we were very skeptical ourselves, but we will definitely use Kiwi in other projects and introduce it to customers.